# Proving that function continuous has a maximum value when function has few properties

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Question: Let $f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ continuous function, which has following properties:

- $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=0$
- $f(0)=2$
- decreasing when, $x\ge2 $

Prove that function has upper bound.

Attempt:

By definition of limit we have there is $A>0$ so that for all $\epsilon >0$

$x < A \Rightarrow | f(x)-0| < \epsilon$.

Now I was thinking that it could be made into closed set, but I don't know how use decreasing property to do that. Some help could be used, please.

Comment: You only need look at $f$ on $(-\infty,2]$, and the first condition shows that you need only consider $f$ on $[-M,2]$ for some $M>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $0<\epsilon<1$. For $-M$ large enough and $x<-M$, $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. $f$ is thus bounded above in $(-\infty, -M)$. Now, consider the interval $[-M, 2]$. This is closed and $f$ continuous so by boundedness theorem we're done. Elsewhere it's decreasing so the same bound works in $(2, \infty)$. This shows the function is bounded above.

Now, simply use the extreme value theorem on $[-M, 2]$ to show that $f$ has a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You chose $A$ such as $x < A \Rightarrow | f(x)| < 2$. Let $I$ the intervall $[A,3]$. $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$, so $f$ is continuous on $I$ and it reachs a maximum on $I$ in $f(c)=m$. $0 \in I$ so $ m \ge 2$, and so $\forall x \le A, f(x)<m$. Also $f$ is decreasing when $x\ge2$, so $\forall x \ge 3, f(x)<m$. Finally $f(c)=m$ is the maximum of $f$ on $\Bbb{R}$.